# JavaScript - Can't seem to 'reset' array passed to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, scope

I am somewhat new to JavaScript, but I am reasonably experienced with programming in general.  I suspect that my problem may have something to do with scoping, or the specifics of passing arrays as parameters, but I am uncertain.

The high-level goal is to have live plotting with several 'nodes', each of which generates 50 points/sec.  I have gotten this working running straight into an array and rendered by dygraphs and C3.js and quickly realized that this is too much data to continually live render.  Dygraphs seems to start impacting the user experience after about 30s and C3.js seems to choke at around 10s.

The next attempt is to decimate the plotted data based on zoom level.

I have data saved into an 'object' which I am using somewhat like a dictionary in other languages.  This is going well using AJAX requests.  The idea is to create a large data buffer using AJAX requests and use the keys to store the data generated by units according to the serial number as the keys.  This is working well and the object is being populated as expected.  I feel that it is informative to know the 'structure' of this object before I get to my question.  It is as follows:

```
{
    1: [[x10,y10], [x11,y11], [...], [x1n, y1n]],
    2: [[x20,y20], [x21,y21], [...], [x2n, y2n]],
    ... : [ ... ]
    a: [[xa0,ya0], [xa1,ya1], [...], [xan, yan]]
}
```

Periodically, a subset of that data will be used to generate a dygraphs plot.  I am decimating the stored data and creating a 'plot buffer' to hold a subset of the actual data.

The dygraphs library takes data in several ways, but I would like to structure it 'natively', which is just an array of arrays.  Each array within the array is a 'row' of data.  All rows must have the same number of elements in order to line up into columns.  The data generated may or may not be at the same time.  If the data x values perfectly match, then the resulting data would look like the following for only two nodes since x10 = x20 = xn0:

```
[
    [x10, y10, y20],
    [x11, y11, y21],
    [ ... ],
    [xan, yan, yan]
]
```

Note that this is just x and y in rows.  In reality, the times for each serial number may not line up, so it may be much closer to:

```
[
    [x10, y10, null],
    [x20, null, y20],
    [x11, y11, y21],
    [ ... ],
    [xan, yan, yan]
]
```

Sorry for all of the background.  We can get to the code tha tI'm having trouble with.  I'm periodically attempting to create the plot buffer using the following code:

```
window.intervalId = setInterval(
    function(){
        var plotData = formatData(nodeData, 45000, 49000, 200);

        /* dygraphs stuff here */
    },
    500
);

function formatData(dataObject, start, end, stride){
    var smallBuffer = [];

    var keys = Object.keys(dataObject);
    keys.forEach(
        function(key){
            console.log('key: ', key);

            mergeArrays(dataObject[key], smallBuffer, start, end, stride);
        }
    );

    return smallBuffer;
}

function mergeArrays(sourceData2D, destDataXD, startInMs, endInMs, strideInMs){
    /* ensure that the source data isn't undefined */
    if(sourceData2D){
        /* if the destDataXD is empty, then basically copy the 
         *  sourceData2D into it as-is taking the stride into account */
        if(destDataXD.length == 0){
            /* does sourceData2D have a starting point in the time range? */
            var startIndexSource = indexNear2D(sourceData2D, startInMs);
            var lastTimeInMs = sourceData2D[startIndexSource][0];

            for(var i=startIndexSource; i < sourceData2D.length; i++){
                /* start to populate the destDataXD based on the stride */
                if(sourceData2D[i][0] >= (lastTimeInMs + strideInMs)){
                    destDataXD.push(sourceData2D[i]);
                    lastTimeInMs = sourceData2D[i][0];
                }

                /* when the source data is beyond the time, then break the loop */
                if(sourceData2D[i][0] > endInMs){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            /* the destDataXD already has data in it, so this needs to use that data
             *  as a starting point to merge the new data into the destination array */
            var finalColumnCount = destDataXD[0].length + 1;
            console.log('final column count: ', finalColumnCount);

            /* add the next column to each existing row as 'null' */
            destDataXD.forEach(
                function(element){
                    element.push(null);
                }
            );

            /* TODO: move data into destDataXD from sourceData2D */

        }
    }
}
```

To add some information since it probably isn't self-explanatory without some effort.  I create two functions, 'formatData' and 'mergeArrays'.  These could have been done in a single function, but it was easier for me to separate out the 'object' domain and the 'array' domain conceptually.  The 'formatData' function simply iterates through all of the data stored in each key, calling the 'mergeArray' routine each time through.  The 'mergeArray' routine is not yet complete and is where I'm having my issue.

The first time through, formatData should be creating an empty array - smallBuffer - into which data is merged using mergeArrays.  The first time executing 'mergeArrays' I see that the smallBuffer is indeed being created and is an empty array.  This empty array is supplied as a parameter to 'mergeArrays' and - the first time through - this works perfectly.  The next time through, the 'smallBuffer' array is no longer empty, so the second case in 'mergeArrays' gets executed.  The first step for me was to calculate the number of columns so that I could pad each row appropriately.  This worked fine, but helped point out the problem.  The next step was to simply append an empty column of 'null' values to each row.  This is where things got weird.  After the 1st time through 'mergeData', the destDataXD still contained 'null' data from the previous executions.  In essence, it appears that the 'var smallBuffer = [];' doesn't actually clear and retains something.  That something is not apparent until near the end.  I can't explain exactly what is going on b/c I don't fully understand it, but destDataXD continually grows 'nulls' at the end without ever being properly reset as expected.

Thank you for the time and I look forward to hearing your thoughts, j

Comment: It would be useful to create a working snippet (with some canned data) to demonstrate the issue, as it stands your snippet fails because `nodeData` does not exist.

Comment: A good thought.  I should have included nodeData.  Thank you for taking the time to look through and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly reading through the code, the danger point I see is where you first add an element to `destDataXD`.

```
destDataXD.push(sourceData2D[i]);
```

Note that you are not pushing a *copy* of the array. You are adding a reference to that array. `destDataXD` and `sourceData2D` are now sharing the same data.

So, of course, when you push any `null` values onto an array in `destDataXD`, you are also modifying `sourceData2D`.

You should use the javascript array-copying method `slice`

```
destDataXD.push(sourceData2D[i].slice());
```

Comment: That is the answer, thank you so much!  I had read that and had implemented the same type of solutions in other portions of the code not visible here, but I didn't see it.  Thank you again, I have spent more than 6 hours trying to find it!